# Get old name and new name after folder rename with ReadDirectoryChangesW C++

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

I'm using `ReadDirectoryChangesW`to identify folder changes.
When I renamed a folder `FILE_ACTION_RENAMED_OLD_NAME` action getting fired and I'm able to get the old name of the folder. But I want to get both old name and new name of that folder.
Is it possible directly from using  `ReadDirectoryChangesW`?

My C++ code is

```
ReadDirectoryChangesW ( hDir, (LPVOID)&strFileNotifyInfo, 
            sizeof(strFileNotifyInfo), 
            TRUE, 
            FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_DIR_NAME, 
            &dwBytesReturned, 
            NULL,
            NULL)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [_FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364391%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). By using `FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION::NextEntryOffset` member variable, you are able to get `FILE_ACTION_RENAMED_NEW_VALUE` as well.

Here is a little code snippet. In your callback,

```
PFILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION info   = NULL;
size_t offset                   = 0;

do 
{
    info = reinterpret_cast<PFILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION>(&buffer[offset]);
    offset += info->NextEntryOffset;

    if(info->Action == FILE_ACTION_ADDED)
    {

    }
    else if(info->Action == FILE_ACTION_REMOVED)
    {

    }
    else if(info->Action == FILE_ACTION_MODIFIED)
    {

    }
    else if(info->Action == FILE_ACTION_RENAMED_OLD_NAME)
    {
        //extract old name by using 'info'
    }
    else if(info->Action == FILE_ACTION_RENAMED_NEW_NAME)
    {
        //extract new name by using 'info'
    }

} while (info->NextEntryOffset != 0);
```

I hope this will help you a little.

Comment: Is it guranteed if the current position is `renamed-from` then is it guranteed the `NextEntryOffset` member is the new name? Are there other situations in which nextEntryOffset is not 0? I have not been able to find any other time where nextEntryOffset is not 0, only for renaming, so i just wanted to make certain.

Comment: I just tested this in Delphi (object pascal), and it would seem that NEW_NAME immediately follows in the buffer